# Random Log outs

Tags: logout

Sometimes, usually not long after resuming from suspend, the screen goes black, then purple, then brings me to the log in screen, where after logging in I have lost all my work as if I have been logged out.

This happens when I'm using Google Chrome, but I couldn't say whether that was defiantly the problem as this only happens on my netbook with I use exclusively for web browsing using Chrome.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with my laptop a while ago, I found this thread useful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9284198#post9284198

> Go to System>Preferences>Screensaver
>   the boxes there are check marked, undo them, I also select 'Power Management' and change to 'never'

Comment: I am using Unity, those options are not present or I cannot find them! If you know how to do this in unity I'd be very grateful!